# Android: ProgressBar Doesnt Work

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-mediaplayer

I'm using media player. I want to show progress bar while connection URL and media player get prepare, but I can't show it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, Runnable{

MediaPlayer mPlayer;
ProgressBar pBar = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Continue();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void Connect()
{           
    try {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Yayın Açılana Kadar Lütfen Bekleyiniz" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    mPlayer.start();
    pBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    pBar.setProgress(0);
    pBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
    new Thread(this).start();
    if(mPlayer!=null)pBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
}
public void Continue()
{
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    String str = "http:MyURL";
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(str);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    Connect();
}
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int currentPosition =0;
    int total = mPlayer.getDuration();
    while(mPlayer!=null && currentPosition<total){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            return;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return;
        }
        pBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference, please try to give a better description of your problem. Telling us that you 'can't' do something gives us no idea what the problem is. Blank screen? Force close? Exception? Phone exploded? Be descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `pBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);` right after starting the thread..it will show and then disappear immediately..
Move it in the run method after the processing is done.

Comment: I removed it to to run method end, but it is still not working.

Comment: ProgressBar.show() doesnt exist. And i m using pBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

Comment: sorry, my fault..where do you initialize it?